# VBA - renaming sheets based on specific order

Tags: excel, vba

I have several workbooks and I'm wondering how one would go about searching for the sheets that are missing, and the renaming the remaining sheets based on the missing sheets.

In the code below (i know it could be written more cleanly, but im not a dev), code_D_14 refers to an existing sheet. The script removes all of the sheets that contain 'code_D_' as the preceding string, but then I am left without several sheets, one of which is the sheet titled 'code_n_14' (it just goes from code_n_13 to code_n_15 - see image below), leaving a gap in the sheets. Is there a way to rename subsequent sheets that occur after 'code_n_14' with a lower integer, and thus, move all the sheets down in value so that there are no spaces (see attached image).

```
Sub AllFiles()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\something\macro_test\"

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
Do While filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
     
    'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
    Call Mymacro
    
    filename = Dir
Loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub

Sub Mymacro()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If Sheet.Name = "code_D_1" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_2" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_3" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_4" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_5" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_6" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_7" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_8" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_9" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_10" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_11" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_12" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_13" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_14" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_15" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_16" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_17" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_18" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_19" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_20" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_21" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_22" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_23" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_24" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_25" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_26" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_27" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_28" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_29" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_30" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_31" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_32" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_33" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_34" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_35" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_36" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_37" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_38" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_39" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_40" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_41" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_42" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_43" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_44" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_45" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_46" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_47" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_48" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_49" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_50" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_51" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_52" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_53" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_54" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_55" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_56" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_57" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_58" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_59" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_60" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_61" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_62" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_63" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_64" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_65" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_66" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_67" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_68" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_69" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     ElseIf Sheet.Name = "code_D_70" Then
            Sheet.Delete
     
     End If
Next Sheet
End Sub
```

My issue is that each workbook has a different number of code_n_x sheets, and each has a different number of code_D_x sheets. By the end of the script, for the current example, the number of code_n_x sheets should end at code_n_55 instead of its current form (code_n_60).

[image]

Comment: no worries. All fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. The code removes all the tabs of a certain value, and then replaces all of the sheets beginning with code_n from code_n_1 right through to whatever.

```
Sub AllFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    folderPath = "C:\Users\shannonbosshard\OneDrive - Australian Radio Network Pty Limited\Desktop\Neuroconsulting\macro_test\"
    
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
    Do While filename <> ""
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
         
        'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
        Call Mymacro
        
        
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
    
    
    Sub Mymacro()
    Dim i As Long, Sheet As Variant
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    i = 1
    
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(Sheet.Name, 7) = "code_D_" Then
            Sheet.Delete
        ElseIf Left(Sheet.Name, 7) = "code_n_" Then
            Sheet.Name = "code_n_" & i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End Sub
```